# Insert or Query with 1 statement

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Using MySQL

With the following table:

```
Idempotent
id VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY
createdAt DATETIME NOT NULL
```

How to do a `INSERT` or `SELECT` with 1 statement?

```
INSERT INTO Idempotent
(id, createdAt)
VALUES
('hello world', '2021-09-23 12:34:56')
ON DUPLICATE KEY **SELECT * FROM Idempotent WHERE (id = 'hello world') **
```

`SELECT` is not allowed for `ON DUPLICATE KEY` so how to do insert or select with 1 statement? Is it even possible?

Comment: `UPDATE` needs to follow `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, not a `SELECT`.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Is there a way to try to `INSERT` and when it fails, `SELECT` using one statement?

Comment: Noway. The query either returns the rowset or not, whereas you want the query to return the rowset only sometimes. Please describe the task itself, not the (incorrect) way which you decide to apply for to solve this task.

Comment: @theAnonymous . . . `INSERT` and `SELECT` are *different* statements.  You can `INSERT` and then `SELECT` the row that was inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM`

```
INSERT INTO Idempotent
(id, createdAt)
SELECT 'hello world', '2021-09-23 12:34:56'
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Multiple runs of the same statement will return`Duplicate entry 'hello world' for key 'idempotent.PRIMARY'`.